# How do I resolve undefined reference errors for template specializations in header?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker-errors

I have 4 files `Colors.h`, `ColorUtils.h`, `Paintbrush.h`, and `Paintbrush.cpp`

`Colors.h` defines an enumeration of colors `COLOR_NAMES` and some color classes `Red`, `Yellow`, `Blue`.

In `Utils.h` I have a template designed to return an enum value based on a type.

```cpp
// ColorUtils.h
#include "Colors.h"
namespace COLORS {
    template <class T> struct TypeToEnum {};

    template<> struct TypeToEnum<Red>    { static const COLOR_NAMES color = COLOR_NAMES::RED; };
    template<> struct TypeToEnum<Yellow> { static const COLOR_NAMES color = COLOR_NAMES::YELLOW; };
    template<> struct TypeToEnum<Blue>   { static const COLOR_NAMES color = COLOR_NAMES::BLUE; };
}
```

In `Paintbrush.h` I try to use these template specializations.

```cpp
// Paintbrush.h
#include "Colors.h"
#include "ColorUtils.h"

namespace COLORS {
    class Paintbrush {
        public: doSomething();
    
        template <class T>
        void printColor { std::cout << to_string(TypeToEnum<T>::color) << std::endl; }
    };
}
```

In `Paintbrush.cpp` I use the function template defined in the header that relies on the template specializations in `Utils.h`

```cpp
// Paintbrush.cpp
#include "Paintbrush.h"

Paintbrush::doSomething() {
    printColor<Red>();
    printColor<Yellow>();
    printColor<Blue>();
}
```

This setup is throwing a lot of linker errors, essentially:

```sh
Paintbrush.o: In function `void Paintbrush::printColor<Red>(): ...
Paintbrush.cpp: ...undefined reference to `COLORS::TypeToEnum<COLORS::Red>::color`
```

Comment: All of my templates are implemented in their respective headers...

Comment: Yeah, the duplicate is not the right one. I'm trying to find one that is not awfully outdated

Comment: I settled to add an answer that is not outdated on the new dupe. But you did tagged C++11, so outdated answers may suit your code better.

Comment: I got so wrapped up in template stuff I failed to see the `static const enum` defined inside my class. Ended up replacing my `static const enum` with a `static` function instead like one of the answers suggests. Unfortunately I'm constrained to gcc4.4 which doesn't support `constexpr`. Thanks for the help!